# Build a multi-directory project with nmake and microsoft compiler

Tags: c, windows, makefile, nmake

I have a C project that needs to be build using with nmake and Microsoft
compiler. The structure of the project is:

```
project_root
|-- parser
|   |-- parser.tab.c
|   |-- Makefile
|-- hashtable
|   |-- hash_table.h
|   |-- hash_table.c
|   |-- Makefile
|-- Makefile
|-- main.c
|-- shell.c
|-- shell.h
```

The Makefile of the project contains rules to build the subprojects parser and
hashtable in each corresponding directory. Relevant excerpts from the main
Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=/W3 /EHsc /nologo /Iparser /Ihashtable 

all: build

run: build
    .\$(EXE)

build: $(EXE)

$(EXE): shell.obj parser\parser.tab.obj hashtable\hash_table.obj
    $(CC) /Fe$(EXE) $**

shell.obj: shell.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /c shell.c

parser.tab.obj: parser

hash_table.obj: hashtable

hashtable:
    cd hashtable && nmake

parser: parser\parser.tab.c parser\parser.yy.c
    cd parser && nmake build_lex
```

The Makefile in the hashtable contains:

```
hash_table.obj: hash_table.c hash_table.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /c hash_table.c
```

When running nmake in the hashtable directory the are no errors or warnings,
but when I run nmake in the main project directory, there are tons of errors
like these:

hashtable\hash_table.h(24) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'

hashtable\hash_table.h(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'

hashtable\hash_table.h(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'

hashtable\hash_table.h(29) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'

hashtable\hash_table.h(59) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'equal_func'

hashtable\hash_table.h(60) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'

hashtable\hash_table.h(63) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'

hashtable\hash_table.h(63) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'ef'

hashtable\hash_table.h(63) : error C2081: 'equal_func' : name in formal parameter list illegal

hashtable\hash_table.h(63) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ef'

hashtable\hash_table.h(63) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'

hashtable\hash_table.h(63) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'

hashtable\hash_table.h(64) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'

hashtable\hash_table.h(64) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'

hashtable\hash_table.h(64) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'

And the relevant lines in the hash_table.h are:

```
21 /* Boolean data type */
22 typedef enum boolean
23 {
24    FALSE = 0,
25    TRUE
26 } boolean_t;
27
28 typedef unsigned int (*hash_func)(const char *str, unsigned int hash_len);
29 typedef boolean_t    (*equal_func)(const char *str1, const char *str2); 

53 typedef struct hashtable
54 {
55     /*
56      * Some code
57      *
58      */
59     equal_func eq_fun;
60 } hashtable_t;
```

What is the problem? There's something wrong with the code or with the
makefiles?

Notes:

1. The same structure works using gcc and gnu make.
2. There is no option to build the project in Visual Studio
3. There is no option to copy file from hashtable and parser directories is the
   main project directory.
4. Renaming hashtable and parser targets does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have not really given enough information for someone to properly answer, which is why it has remained unanswered for so long, I can see some areas where the problem might lie.

You have probably jumped to conclusions about what causes the problem and by giving "Relevant excerpts" you have hidden information we need to reproduce the problem and find an answer.

For example, When you do this:

```
parser: parser\parser.tab.c parser\parser.yy.c
    cd parser && nmake build_lex
```

You do not have parser.yy.c in the directory. We see no information on how flex and bison are called. I see many errors from people building flex and bison programs by either putting an include in the wrong location in the *.l and *.y files, or failing to notice that there are errors in the flex and bison source causing incorrect code to be generated. These causes need to be eliminated before we can go and look at the makefile.

Is this class work that you should have asked your tutor about?